# Datatype not supported in SQL Server 2008 while creating trigger

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, triggers, types

Which Datatypes are not supported in SQL Server 2008 while creating trigger

Answer (score 2):

With compatibility level 70; text,ntext, and image column type are not allowed with trigger (insert,delete,update)

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server 2008 DML(insert, delete, update) triggers does not allow column references to text, ntext and image in the inserted, deleted tables if the compatibility level is 70.

Read more about it here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx

In fact these data types won't be supported in future versions of SQL Server and varchar(max), nvarchar(max) and varbinary(max) are recommended instead.

To read on compatibility level check this http://venkattechnicalblog.blogspot.com/2008/05/compatibility-level-in-sql-server.html

cheers